# PHP kill process after inactivity

Tags: php

I have a script which may o may not become inactive after some time as it requests information from a very slow server with short session expire time.
The script `echo`s into the shell after each of its process is done as my way of debugging the code. Is there any way of executing the script from another script and killing it after some time the last `echo`. In other word, kill the script after inactive.
**EDIT**: here we can se an example of my code:

```
foreach ($info["Ten_Friends"] as $friend) {
    $info = [];
    echo "11111 \n";
    $info = $i->userAnalysis($friend);
    if ($info != false) {
        echo "if to database\n";
        if (($i->usersDatabase($info) == true)) {
            mediaDataBase($info);
            $nAnalized += 1;
            echo "nAnalized: ".$nAnalized."\n";
        }
    } else {echo $friend." not analised";}

    echo "3333\n";
}
```

As you can see, I `echo` after each process. Both `$i->userAnalysis($friend);` and `$i->usersDatabase($info)` request data to the server this functions may become unresponsive after some time, so I need to kill the script if they do so.
Running Php 5.6 on Osx El Capitan and mysql

Comment: Please add your code. Read here to see how to form a [mcve]

Comment: @amflare here's an example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$cmd = "php AnalyzeFriends.php";
$timeout_tolerance = 10; // 10 seconds
$last_response = time(); // start time

ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();

$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),   // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),   // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("pipe", "w")    // stderr is a pipe that the child will write to
);
flush();
$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, realpath('./'), array());
echo "<pre>";
if (is_resource($process)) {
    while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
        print $s;
        if((time() - $last_response) > $timeout_tolerance){
          fclose($pipes[0]);
          fclose($pipes[1]);
          fclose($pipes[2]);
          proc_close($process);
        }
        $last_response = time();
        flush();
    }
}
echo "</pre>";
```

Run this as a seperate script that can call your script you have posted, look for the echos, if it doesn't recieve an echo for

Comment: thanks for the answer, what would the `$pipe` variable stand for?